# Battleship programme placing ships in a blob

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Battleship application for one person where the computer places 3 ships of 3 places on the map. So that makes 9 places for ships in the end. The player then shoots and everything of that works.

The problem I'm having is that my ships keep getting placed on a little heap, more like an island, which is really not what I want.

This is the code for the placing of the ships..

```
    int num_Ship = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            sink_This[i][j] = 'o';
            show_This[i][j] = 'o';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        while (( start_PosX > 7) || (start_PosX == 0))
        {
            start_PosX = (int) randomGen();
        }

        while (( start_PosY > 7) || (start_PosY == 0))
        {
            start_PosY = (int) randomGen();
        }

        direction_Pos = (int) randomGen();
        if (( direction_Pos >= 0) &&( direction_Pos <= 4))
        {
            sink_This[start_PosX][start_PosY - 1] = 'x';
            sink_This[start_PosX][start_PosY] = 'x';
            sink_This[start_PosX][start_PosY + 1] = 'x';
        } else 
        {
            sink_This[start_PosX - 1][start_PosY] = 'x';
            sink_This[start_PosX][start_PosY] = 'x';
            sink_This[start_PosX + 1][start_PosY] = 'x';
        }
    }


    while (num_Ship < 9)
    {
        num_Ship = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if (sink_This[i][j] == 'x')
                {
                    num_Ship++;
                }
            }
        }


        if (num_Ship < 9)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    if ((sink_This[i][j] == 'x') && (j > 0) && (j < 9))
                    {
                        sink_This[i][j - 1] = 'x';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the randomGen() if anyone is wondering.

```
    private Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    final double randomGen()
    {
        return generator.nextDouble() * 10;
    }
```

An example of what the 2d array looks like after this is:

```
o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o

o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o

o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o

o.o.o.x.x.x.o.o.o

o.o.x.x.x.x.x.o.o

o.o.o.x.x.x.o.o.o

o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o

o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o

o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o
```

Every time it is the same shape of x's.

Any help as to why it's placing the ships like it is would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: No, i have not. I am unsure as to how to do this... I'm still quite a beginner

Comment: Use an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA is my favourite), click on the margin to get a red dot on the first line of the method, click on the bug icon, and experiment with the interface that appears.

Comment: If you look [Random#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) you can specify the max number to randomise, hence eliminating the need for your while loops and a lot of your if statements.

Comment: Oh, that debugging is very helpful. Thank-you =)

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int start_PosX = 0;
    int start_PosY = 0;
```

So move the declaration of the start position inside the loop for every ship.
Otherwise the second ship (i == 1) reuses the old start position.

Now every ship has its own start position variables.

Hints:

```
while (( start_PosY > 7) || (start_PosY == 0))
```

can be rewritten as:

```
while (start_PosY > 7 || start_PosY == 0)
```

And [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) may be uses as:

```
Random random = new Random();
...
start_PosX = random.nextInt(9);
```

The constructor with a long parameter, is primarily intended for *repeatable* sequences of random numbers. And `nextInt(9)` gives an element from 0, 1, 2, ..., 8.

Comment: +1 Good catch. They could also just implement `Random.nextInt(maxNum)` to eliminate the need for the while and still ensuring the value is random and valid for each iteration :)

Comment: @JavaDevil we got the same idea. Added remark on constructor too, and javadoc link.